# SSRS 2005 -Set Visibility based on dataset rowcount

Tags: reportingservices-2005, visibility, reporting-services

I have a line and a table in my report that I want to hide if my dataset has no rows in it.

I tried using the expression `=CountRows("MyDataSet") > 0` in the initial visibility but this always evaluates to false, even when there are rows in the dataset.

I suspect initial visibility is run before the data is loaded into the dataset.

How can I set the visibility of my table and other elements (a line), based on if the dataset has any rows or not?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This appears to work in `2008` - hopefully it will help ...

I created a `DataSet` with one record in it.  I then created a text box and put your code in the 'Hidden' property in the `Visibility` Properties section.

I then changed it to

```
=CountRows("MyDataSet") < 1
```

Which will return `TRUE` when there are no rows, which will set the control to hidden.

Answer (score 13):

Use `=IIF(CountRows("DataSet1") > 0, false, true)` inside the expression of visibility property of the control.

Answer (score 0):

Worked totally

```
=IIF(CountRows("OpenItem_DS") < 1,"", "Wk No")
```